# "View Source" option is always disable in Live Visual Tree Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

From last 2 weeks, the "View Source" option is disabled in my Visual Studio 2017 IDE. I don't what went wrong suddenly, but I used to use it a lot and always worked fine for me.

Somebody else faced the same issue, please let me know if we can do something to fix this.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In release mode, the XAML Hot Reload is disabled by default, changing it to debuy mode solved the problem for me, see [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019#verify-that-your-msbuild-properties-are-correct) if you want solution for release mode as well.